# Same variablename and propertyname in a constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, variables, properties, constructor

Consider the following definition of a class in JavaScript:

```
// Car constructor
function Car(color) {
    var hasWheels = true;
    this.color = color;
    this.hasWheels = hasWheels;
}
var redCar = new Car('red');
console.log(redCar.hasWheels);
```

It seems to work because it gives no errors in Firefox and writes `true` to the console. However, is this code correct or is JavaScript just too forgiving? Netbeans complains that in the Car constructor the variable `hasWheels` is unused. Also it does not give a hint to `hasWheels` when I type `redCar.`. This works properly with the property `color`. So do I have to rename my variable `hasWheels` to e.g. `_hasWheels`? (I know that in this simple example I could just set the property `hasWeels` directly to `true`, but this is not the point of my question.) So the new code would look like:

```
// Car constructor
function Car(color) {
    var _hasWheels = true;
    this.color = color;
    this.hasWheels = _hasWheels;
}
var redCar = new Car('red');
console.log(redCar.hasWheels);
```

This seems to work fine with NetBeans. However, I rather like to gives the properties and the variables the same name, since they are at the end assigned. Also `this['hasWheels'] = hasWheels` in the last line of the constructor seems not to work.

For what it is worth this works fine in NetBeans:

```
function Car(color) {
    var hasWheels = true;
    return {
        color: color,
        hasWheels: hasWheels
    };
}
var redCar = new Car('red');
console.log(redCar.hasWheels);
```

Comment: That sounds like a NetBeans issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can have the same name.  A function argument is in the same namespace as the function's local variables, but the properties of the object itself are completely different.

You can think of arguments and local variables as items on the local scope object (or scope chain) whereas properties of the current object are properties of the object pointed to by `this`.  Those two namespaces are different.  One is reached with no qualifier as in `color`.  The other is only reached by referencing the object as in `this.color`.  So, `this.color = color` works just fine - assigning a variable's value from one namespace to a property in another object's namespace - two completely separate variables.

In your example that you say doesn't work:

```
// Car constructor
function Car(color) {
    var hasWheels = true;
    this.color = color;
    this.hasWheels = hasWheels;
}
```

there should be no issue there either and it seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7PSg9/

Comment: It is not that the code does not work. Rather it is NetBeans that does not recognize the porperty if I write like this. So I was wondering whether there is 'something' wrong with it. But maybe there is just something wrong with NetBeans here... Surprisingly NetBeans does not complain about the `color` property...

Comment: @Daniel - there's nothing wrong with it from Javascript's point of view, so the issue is purely with NetBeans.  You will have to decide whether you want to make NetBeans happy, but there's no Javascript reason to change it.